# Selective Predicate Pushdown To View

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, where-clause, predicate

I have a large column store table that gets frequent updates. I don't ingest the updates directly into the source table because that would cause, in most cases, a small number of updates to cause a full table micro partition rebuild. Instead I stream updates to an update table, and at query time I combine both. In practice this works out well.

So simplify things, i'll throw this in a view `users_view`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_view AS (
    SELECT * FROM users
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM user_changes
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY id 
        ORDER BY last_updated_at DESC
    ) = 1
)
```

Both the `users` table and `user_changes` table have the same scheme as well as the some partition configuration. This way I can use predicate pushdown on the view to only select users within the correct partition. Let's say this is the `account_id`.

```
SELECT * FROM users_view
WHERE account_id = 1234
```

But the `users` table is quite a bit larger than the `user_changes` table, and I'd like to push even more predicates down to the `users` table without pushing additional predicates down to the `user_changes` table. Why? Because matching on the `users` table, while 98% accurate, has false positives/negatives. The details from the `user_changes` are needed to set the record straight. What this would look like outside of a view is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE account_id = 1234 AND city = 'Chicago'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM user_changes
    WHERE account_id = 1234
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY id 
        ORDER BY last_updated_at DESC
    ) = 1
)
WHERE account_id = 1234 AND city = 'Chicago'
```

As nasty as this looks, it's much more performant. All conditions can be applied to the much larger `users` table, but only unchanging conditions can be applied to the `users_changes` table. i.e. A user may change cities, but a user can't change accounts. The second run of all conditions after the union is to catch any changes the `user_changes` introduced.

This is cumbersome to write, and even more so as the query becomes complicated and query builders get involved. So i'm looking for way way to convince the sql planner to skip predicate pushdown of some predicates on my `user_changes` table without needing to format the query like this. Ideally with a view.

**PSUEDO SQL. PSUEDO SQL. PSUEDO SQL**

In my wildest dreams I could tell the query planner where it can use partition predicates, and where it can use non-partition predicates.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW users_view AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM users
        %PARTITION_PREDICATES%
        %NON_PARTITION_PREDICATES%

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT * FROM user_changes
        %PARTITION_PREDICATES%

        QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY id 
            ORDER BY last_updated_at DESC
        ) = 1
    )
    %PARTITION_PREDICATES%
    %NON_PARTITION_PREDICATES%
)

SELECT * FROM users_view
WHERE account_id = 1234 AND city = 'Chicago'
```

Any crazy ideas?

Comment: Are you creating view with predicates already hardcoded? If I got your problem right, you want to to simplifyquery building to make it possible to apply predicates only at the end of query (still inside the view)?

Comment: Ideally I would like to treat the view as a blackbox that _knows_ how to apply the correct predicates to each table. I want to apply full predicates to my `users` table, but hand pick which predicates to apply to the `user_changes` table. So yes- this would be to simplify the query building process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add additional column `src` for determining the source table and wrap predicates in the CASE:

```
select * from
(
SELECT u.*, 'users' as src FROM users u
union all
SELECT uc.*, 'users_changes' as src FROM users_changes uc
) 
WHERE --applied only to users
      case when src  = 'users' 
                 then city = 'Chicago' --predicate wrapped in case
           else true
       end
  --applied to all
  AND account=12345
```

Comment: Very cool idea! Thank you!

Comment: @micah you can wrap all predicates in single CASE using  AND or OR: `then city = 'Chicago' AND one_more_condition AND some_other_condition`